# How to disable particular dates in vue-simple-calendar?

Tags: vue.js, calendar, vuejs3

I am using ***[vue-simple-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-calendar)*** for my vue3 UI. So in there I have to disable the previous weeks and the future weeks. It should only enable current week.

Is there any way to disable particular dates in vue-simple-calendar?

Answer (score 0):

you can use (disabled) property in calendar's tag

Comment: Thanks @user16225268 for the response. 

Actually there is no "disabled" property in the [vue-simple-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-calendar)

there is just "disable-<future/past>" property which make disabling the navigating to next or previous month. And its a boolean property